# TFS workspace issue after upgrade 2008 to 2010

Tags: tfs, upgrade, workspace

I've just upgraded TFS 2008 to 2010 following the instruction 
http://blog.hinshelwood.com/upgrading-team-foundation-server-2008-to-2010/

During TFS 2010 install and upgrade process I was logged in as domain user "A".

Everything is fine, but:
I open solution in Visual Studio (2010) on the client computer working as domain user "B", do some changes and check in.
And this changeset is shown as made by user "A". That definetly should not be so.

I tried:

Deleting all workspaces for client computer locally using command
tf workspace /remove:*
and on TFS using Team Foundation Sidekicks.

Reconnect to TFS in VS and the workspace for user "A" was recreated!

I manually changed owner of this workspace to user "B" and it was disappeared, i.e. Workspace dropdownlist shows "No workspaces available" string. But Sidekicks now shows correct workspace existance for user "B".

It seems that VS connects to TFS as "A" user. I wonder why it happens? As I logged in domain as "B".

Comment: Are domain users "A" and "B" related in any way?  Do they have similar domain names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of problem. There was the entry in Stored User Names and Passwords. So Windows always connected to the computer with TFS as user "A".
I removed this saved credential and everything goes fine now.